# capacitor plugin filesystem is not complete when using bundledWebRuntime:true

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I'm trying to use the Filesystem plugin of capacitor v3 with bundledWebRuntime as I'm not using Ionic.
However Directory or Encoding can not be found as the structure of the plugin variable is wrong:

```
console.log(Capacitor);
//Plugins->Filesystem->readFile

//but it should be
//Plugins->Filesystem->filesystem->readFile

//Plugins->Filesystem->Directory->...
//Plugins->Filesystem->Encoding->..
```

Comment: bundledWebRuntime only bundles capacitor code, not the plugins code

Comment: Great. And how do I bundle the plugin code? npm install @capacitor/filesystem is not enough?

Comment: If you want to target web you’ll have to configure some bundler (webpack, pika, etc). If you only target ios/android then everything should still work even without bundling plugins.

Comment: I'm targeting Android/ Ios but I'm using no framework like Ionic. Just plain ol jquery and a ui framework (css only+ some jquery functions for transitions/dialogues).

Comment: Then everything is ok, Directory and Encoding are types and you are not using typescript, you have to check the actual values, in example, instead of Directory.Data use 'DATA'

Comment: A got it! Thanks! Why couldn't I have fought of this before? It seems obvious, but was not documented this way!